# Color setting in Angular

Tags: html, angular, colors, styles, project

I have a project in Angular that has a file called "Colors.sass" in a folder called Style.sass where all the colors are defined. I would like to know if it was possible through certain implementations, to insert the possibility to change this colors.sass file according to the project needs, that is, if in a project I need these components created to have different colors how can I change this?

Comment: No you can't because SASS compiles the code. But what you can do is use CSS variables directly instead, and those ones you can change (although with weird behaviors)

Comment: and you can create a separate page on the site and change the variables present in the sass \ css directly from there?